# Iteration through list with for

Tags: python, list, iteration

I'm quite a newbie in Python.
Imagine I have a list `[100, 200, 300, 301, 315, 345, 500]`. I want to create a new list out of it, like `[100, 200, 300, 500]`.

When I iterate through the list like that:

```
for i in range(len(list)):
    while (list[i+1] - 100) <= list[i]:
        i = i + 1
        k = list[i]
```

Then changes of `i` within while loop are not reflected for `i` within for loop, so I iterate multiple times through the same elements.

What would be the better way to change the code to avoid that?

Answer (score 5):

Here's how I'd do it

```
>>> mylist = [100,200,300,301,315,345,500]
>>> [x for x in mylist if x % 100 == 0]
[100, 200, 300, 500]
```

**EDIT:** On closer inspection of your algorithm, it seems you're actually trying to build a list of the values that are larger than the previous value plus 99. In that case, this will work:

```
def my_filter(lst):
    ret = [lst[0]]
    for i1, i2 in zip(lst, lst[1:]):
        if i2 - i1 >= 100:
            ret.append(i2)
    return ret
```

The above algorithm works like this:

```
>>> my_filter([101, 202, 303, 305, 404, 505])
[101, 202, 303, 505]
```

Answer (score 1):

`range(len(list))` will look at the list length *once* and then create a range-iterator out of it which is then completely separated from both the list and its length.

So `for i in range(len(list))` will make `i` go from `0` to `len(list)-1`, without respecting changes of the list. Also note that updating the iterator variable `i` within the loop will not affect the loop itself at all. When the next iteration starts, `i` will just get the next value, regardless of if you wanted to skip an interation by incrementing `i` before.

To skip iterations you usually use the `continue` statement, which will just abort the current iteration and start with the next `i`.

In respect of your actual problem, you seem to want to filter all numbers which are multiples of 100. You can check that for a single number much easier by checking if you can divide it by 100 without any remainders. For this you use the [modulo operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation), which will give you the remainder for a division. Combined with a list comprehension in which you filter for those, you can write it simply like this:

```
>>> lst = [100, 200, 300, 301, 315, 345, 500]
>>> [n for n in lst if n % 100 == 0]
[100, 200, 300, 500]
```

Also note that you shouldn’t name your variables `list` as that will overwrite the reference to the `list` type.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but actually my aim is a bit more complex. The list was just an example. Sorry, for being unprecise, but I did not want to go too much into details and give too complex description. I have some sliding windows and two lists are keeping the start and end positions for each window. I want to filter out overlapping or adjacent windows. When the next element in the list is very close to the previous, then I want to iterate through the list until I find element that is far enough, as soon as I'll find it, I can access corresponding element from the second list.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
def my_filter(xs):
    ys = []
    for x in xs:
        if (not ys) or ys[-1] + 100 <= x:
            ys.append(x)
    return ys
my_filter([100, 200, 300, 301, 315, 345, 500])  >> [100, 200, 300, 500]
```

Comment: Note that this algorithm produces a different result than mine on some inputs. For example, for the input `[100, 150, 200]`, your function outputs `[100, 200]`, while mine produces `[100]`. I'm not sure what OP really wanted though, since the input and output he chose matches all three algorithms given so far in these answers.

Comment: Thank you, for your answer. The thing is that, I'll need then also index for each element. So, in my example, once I go through 301,315,345 and find 500, I have to get the corresponding 6th element from another list... and, yes, I do need the last value as well.

Comment: @Malfet You can use `enumerate` to get both the element and its index.

Comment: I did it! Thanks to all. I found a different way, but it's working :)