# Iterate over list into variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

How to set the value of variable to index 1 first then change that to index 2 and so on in loop.

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = x[1]
n = len(x)
# Editor: variables to make code runnable
T = 2
M = 1
c = 0
i = 0
a = 0
while (i < n):
        a += T * c + ( b - M )
        c = a 
        i = i + 1
print(a)
```

In the above code the value of `b` should be changed from index 1 to index 2 and continue. Each time the equation `a += T * c + ( b - M )` continues the value of 'b' should be changed from one index to another index value.

Comment: So you are trying to iterate `x` but from the second element? Then do `for i in x[1:]:`

Comment: `b = x[2]`? What are you trying to accomplish exactly? It would help to provide complete code and expected output, similar to a [mre]. Please [edit] to clarify. BTW, welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iteration through list with for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16439367/iteration-through-list-with-for)

Comment: @VirtualScooter I mean the value of 'b' should be change from index 1 to index 2 then index3 when the loop continues. The equation 'a += T * c + ( b - M )' should be continue with 'b' value equals to index 2 in second times and 'b' value equals  to index 3 in third time. The value of 'b' should be changed each time.

Comment: @gribvirus74 I mean the value of 'b' should be change from index 1 to index 2 then index3 when the loop continues. The equation 'a += T * c + ( b - M )' should be continue with 'b' value equals to index 2 in second times and 'b' value equals to index 3 in third time. The value of 'b' should be changed each time.

Comment: @wjandrea yes. But the value of b  should be changed from one index value to another index value until the loop executes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let me attempt to fix the code from the question with the "non-Pythonic" answer:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = x[1]
n = len(x)
T = 2
c = 0
M = 1
i = 0
a = 0
while (i < n):
    b = x[i]
    a += T * c + ( b - M )
    c = a
    i = i + 1
print(a)
# 58
```

A more "Pythonic" approach would be:

```
T = 2
c = 0
M = 1
a = 0
for b in x:
    a += T * c + ( b - M )
    c = a
print(a)
# 58
```